# How to filter checkboxes using JQuery 2.1.4?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to select and de-select all check boxes given in table column. I have already done code for JQuery version 1.4.0 but, after upgrading version to 2.1.4 it has stopped working.

The problem where I am getting in my code is here:

```
function findCheckBoxes(selectid, table) {
    return $(table).find('td input:checkbox:not(:disabled):[id*=' + selectid + ']');
}
```

It is throwing error:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: td input:checkbox:not(:disabled):[id*=chkselect]
```

If I remove the further filter from the find function then it works fine but, I also want to filter the disabled and specific column checkboxes.

```
function findCheckBoxes(selectid, table) {
    return $(table).find('td input:checkbox');
}
```

But, It selects all checkboxes not from particular column.

**Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FAYJS/475/)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the `:` before `[id*=` which creates an invalid selector

```
$(table).find('td input:checkbox:not(:disabled)[id*=' + selectid + ']');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ad60s36s/)